# write function parameter inside file - Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a function which prints messages. then I want to save this messages into a file. But when I use `.write(function parameter)` it only write last message inside my file

`writing_in_log = True
def print_and_log(message):
     if write_in_log is True:
         logFile = open("log", "w+")
         logFile.write(message)
         logFile.close()`

Comment: Please provide the full code you 're using.

Comment: Thank you I found out that problem was that I opened file in writing mode. I had to open in appending mode and it works fine by now

Comment: @VasilisG. no, not *full code*.  Create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @TobySpeight you 're right, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are not using the `'a'` parameter when opening the file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('function parameter')
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably open the file for each writing with `open(yourfile, 'w')` which will erase any content from the file before you write to it. If you want to append to your file, use [`open(yourfile, 'a')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r).

In case this is not the error we need more information about what you are doing, i.e. the relevant parts of the code.